# IIS showing server error instead of custom errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, server-error

I'm using MVC 5 and I'm handling my errors with a custom views for errors such as (404, 403.. etc)
It works fine on my local IIS but when I publish on a **staging server** it shows the IIS server error messages regarding these error codes.

**It's showing this message:**

[image: Showing this message]

**instead of:**

[image: instead of this]

I have modified the `web.config` for `<customErrors mode="Off" />`

**Global.asax**

```
        if ((Context.Server.GetLastError() is UnauthorizedAccessException))
        {
            log.LogError(Context.Server.GetLastError().Message, Context.Server.GetLastError());
            customErrorPage = @"~/Error/?id=403"; //security
        }
        else if ((Context.Server.GetLastError() is HttpException) && (((HttpException)Context.Server.GetLastError()).GetHttpCode() == 404))
        {
            //** Handle 404 error and response code
            log.LogError("404", Context.Server.GetLastError());
            customErrorPage = @"~/Error/?id=404";
        }
        else
        {
            log.LogError(Context.Server.GetLastError().Message, Context.Server.GetLastError());
            customErrorPage = @"~/Error";
        }

        if (ConfigurationHelper.Common.ShowCustomErrorPage)
        {
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
            Response.Redirect(urlHelper.Content(customErrorPage), false);
            Server.ClearError();
        }
```

**Error controller:**

```
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) && id.Equals("404"))
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 404;
            return !Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? (ActionResult)View("404") : PartialView("404");
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) && id.ToLower().Equals("403"))
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 403;
            return !Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? (ActionResult)View("Security") : PartialView("Security");
        }
        return !Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? (ActionResult)View("Index") : PartialView("Index");
    }
```

What should I do in-order to show my custom error messages?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add the following `web.config` configuration to pass through IIS default error handling behavior

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That works just great but it will completely remove IIS level 404 error handling. If you have a URL that is not handled by ASP.NET engine, it won't return 404 not found error.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

at your controller.
It's better than the

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

as the `PassThrough` can cause some results you don't always expect. For example read [here](https://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/what-to-expect-from-iis7-custom-error-module) how it will make custom error module return blank response if modules don’t set any text.